# How to set the 1st item in GridView to be a button?

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, adapter

I have a GridView with groups that a user belongs to. I want to have the first item in GridView (1st column, 1st row) to be a button to create a new group.
I've tried to add an if in getView():

```
if (position == 0) {
   return button
}
```

But it doesn't work. Also I'm not sure where to put that button in .xml file and how to position it.

**EDIT**

The button appears in the View although it's not in the 1st column 1st row position:

```
override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
          var convertView = view
          val holder: UsersViewHolder
          if (layoutInflater == null) {
              layoutInflater =
                  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
          }
          if (convertView == null) {
              usersBinding = ItemGridGroupBinding.inflate(layoutInflater!!)
              convertView = usersBinding.root
              holder = UsersViewHolder()
              holder.name = usersBinding.nazwaGrupy
              holder.img = usersBinding.avatarGrupy
              holder.button = usersBinding.btnAddGroup
              convertView.tag = holder
          }
          else {
              holder = convertView.tag as UsersViewHolder
          }
          if(position == 0) {
              holder.button?.visibility = VISIBLE
          }
          else if(position > 0){
              holder.button?.visibility = GONE
              holder.name!!.text = this.grupy!![position].name
             Picasso.get().load(grupy[position].img).into(holder.img)
          }

          return convertView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

1. keep button in your recycle item XML with property visibility GONE.
2. In adaptor use below condition-

> ```
> if (position == 0) {
>    holder.button.setvisibility(VISIBLE)
> } else {
>    holder.button.setvisibility(GONE)
> }
> ```

hope you understood.

Comment: Thank you! The button finally appeared at the screen! Although it's not in the position == 0. I think it's because  I'm reading the user's group list first? Checkout the code, I've edited my question